# OCMock: Make a stub do something

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm getting used to OCMock. Coming from a Java/JMock background I'm now looking for the ability to say `[[[myMock stub] returnValueFromCustomMethod] someMockedMethod];` where `returnValueFromCustomMethod` is defined in the test class. I was originally thinking something along the terms of `[[[myMock stub] usingSelector:@selector(myMethod:)] someMockedMethod];` but after writing I wonder if my first approach makes more sense. Either way, could someone show me if and how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was off-track: OCMock doesn't support this! If you wanted to change OCMock to support this, you would need to do something like adding a `BOOL returnValueIsFromInvocation` field to OCMockRecorder, and add a method to set this up:

```
- (id)andReturnResultOfInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
  returnValueIsFromInvocation = YES;
  returnValueIsBoxed = NO;
  returnValueShouldBeThrown = NO;
  [returnValue autorelease];
  returnValue = [anInvocation retain];
  return self;
}
```

Then teach `setUpReturnValue` to call the invocation (changes are in bold):

```
- (void)setUpReturnValue:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
  if (returnValueIsFromInvocation) {
    NSInvocation *returnValueInvocation = (NSInvocation *)returnValue;
    [returnValueInvocation invoke];
    void *buffer = malloc([[anInvocation methodSignature] methodReturnLength]);
    [returnValueInvocation getValue:buffer];
    [anInvocation setReturnValue:buffer];
    free(buffer);
  }
  else if(returnValueShouldBeThrown)
  {
    @throw returnValue;
  }
  else if(returnValueIsBoxed)
  {
    if(strcmp([[anInvocation methodSignature] methodReturnType],
              [(NSValue *)returnValue objCType]) != 0)
      [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException
                  format:@"Return value does not match method signature."];
    void *buffer = malloc([[anInvocation methodSignature] methodReturnLength]);
    [returnValue getValue:buffer];
    [anInvocation setReturnValue:buffer];
    free(buffer);
  }
  else
  {
    const char *returnType = [[anInvocation methodSignature] methodReturnType];
    const char *returnTypeWithoutQualifiers = returnType + (strlen(returnType) - 1);
    if(strcmp(returnTypeWithoutQualifiers, @encode(id)) == 0)
      [anInvocation setReturnValue:&returnValue];   
  }
}
```

This change is difficult to do by introducing subclasses because you have to override the methods that return OCMockRecorders (like `stub`, `expect` and so on) but the concrete subclasses of OCMockObject (OCClassMockObject and OCProtocolMockObject) are hidden by the framework.